# How can I donate money to Academia Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

Recently my uncle passed away and left me with a rather large inheritance, much of which I do not anticipate ever having a need for.  How can I donate money - in USD - to Academia Stack Exchange - its employees, top contributors, and moderators?  Note that I desire my donation to be specific to the Academia site and not to the whole of Stack Exchange.

Please advise, and thank you.

Comment: As a sceptic: This sounds like an example of the scams I receive by email. (Admittedly it reads better than most examples.) Especially as the OP is a new user, as of today.

Comment: I do not know the scams you speak of, @user2768; further, I am not aware of any other forms of communication with Academia Stack Exchange other than through asking a question.

Comment: @user83000 You might well have honourable motives. Equally you might not. We simply cannot know. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog.) My comment serves only as a warning.

Comment: @user83000: there are a number of [deposit and refund scams](https://www.nedbank.co.za/content/nedbank/desktop/gt/en/aboutus/legal/fraud-awareness/deposit-and-refunding-scams.html) that all start with strangers saying "hey can I give you some money."

Comment: @user2768 if you were planning to ask a question similar to OP’s, wouldn’t you create a new user for this purpose? I know I would, rather than advertise my intentions publicly with my current academia.se (and in my case, my real-life) identity. This may or may not be a scam/hoax, but the fact that OP is asking as a new user says nothing.

Comment: Here is the contact page for the StackExchange company: https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact. I’m sure they’d be happy to discuss your philanthropic ideas.

Comment: @DanRomik I don't disagree. That said, the post caught my attention. It is the first such message I have seen on stackexchange.com. If the message is indeed a scam, then a new trend might well follow and it is worth identifying.

Comment: @user2768 there is a first time for everything. And I know from experience that there are a lot of people out there with good will towards academia (and by extension, it’s not a stretch to imagine some of that good will being directed at academia.se specifically). My department regularly receives fairly large donations from kind individuals. Anyway, I don’t see why we shouldn’t take the question at face value.

Comment: This seems extremely strange.  Money is power, and when it comes to donation, the central question is how to apply that power for the betterment of some cause.  Simply "_I want to give people money I just got through inheritance_" doesn't sound like a real human thing, and on the off-chance that this is a sincere offer, it would be inappropriate for SE.Academics to accept it; rather, you should be advised that merely throwing what little money you have at people is a poor path toward effecting positive change (which is why it's not typically done in the first place).

Comment: If you actually have come into a large sum of money that, for whatever reason, you're determined to give away, then it'd probably be wise to first hire a financial advisor who'll discuss your objectives and the best way to achieve them, even if that desire is to advance some cause by injecting it with cash.  Large sums of money _are_ able to help bring about significant good, but only if applied wisely; so if you're honestly trying to do something good, get a professional to help you determine how to do that well, rather than blow the opportunity on some frivolous gesture.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Exchange is a for-profit company, it cannot legally take donations (as far as I know, but I am not a lawyer). There are also no employees specific to the "academia" site. The contributors and moderators in question could presumably receive a gift (not a donation, and especially not a tax-exempt donation) if you asked them individually to divulge their financial information, but they have no group structure that could receive or manage money.

You may be able to buy some site contributors a coffee, but you won't be able to support the functioning of this website with a donation.

(There are also various pitfalls with introducing money into a community that works essentially as a gift economy, so IMO you should look for other worthy causes.)

Comment: Well, I assume there is no group structure. If there is in fact a secret cabal, feel free to correct me, moderators ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I shall wait for clarification from the moderators.

Comment: I think none of the objections you raise would be really problematic if the sum of money that OP wanted to donate were large enough. E.g., many for-profits have non-profit subsidiaries that do charitable work in keeping with the parent comoant’s mission. OP could approach StackExchange with an offer to give money (say, to endow scholarships for graduate students) and ask them to help administer the funds or even to add their own matching contribution. Again, if there was a common interest I think they might be cooperative (though I have no formal affiliation with them so I can’t say for sure).

Comment: Endowing scholarships for graduate students sounds like one of those "other worthy causes" I endorse. I don't think going through Academia.SE is really a good way to achieve that, though...

Comment: Also, your comment made me realize that we are picturing vastly different sums. I was thinking of maybe $10k, tops - what would a bunch of people who like answering questions even do with that much money? - but that only buys you half a year of a graduate student. OP, how much money are you willing to spend, and what is your goal here? Would you simply like to support the site to continue doing what it is doing? Reward the contributors for being good people? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Requests like this should be made directly to the Stack Exchange team. Contact information is listed on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact), which I found on the footer of this page. Thanks!